# Is it possible to use Handoff without requiring the user to open from the lockscreen?( Apple Watch)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, watchkit, handoff

I am attempting to continue a task from the Apple Watch to the iPhone and would like to launch the parent application to the foreground with relevant data to continue with the workflow. I know using

```
WKInterfaceController.openParentApplication()
```

will not bring to foreground so that's out. I've attempted to use a custom URL scheme to launch from within the parent app using

```
application(application: UIApplication, handleWatchKitExtensionRequest userInfo:
```

in the AppDelegate via

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string:"openForCall://open")!)
```

That didn't seem to work and then now I've implemented handoff which works fine except for the fact the user needs to active from the lockscreen and slide up from the icon on the left. Is it possible to bring an app into the foreground (legally, meaning Apple Approved method) via some other method? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

No this is not possible right now. User has to manually launch the app on iPhone by sliding up on lock screen if you're using handoff.